# Symfony2 - Root slugs for different content types

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I would like to have multiple routes that only have one path "part" within the URI, but load different types of content.

For example I want to have pages created using a CMS to be loaded via `/page-slug-here`. However I also want products to be loaded via `/product-slug-here`, categories loaded via `/category-slug-here`, brands loaded via `/brand-slug-here`, etc.

What's the best / most dynamic way of achieving this with Symfony2, without having a complicated (and inefficient) chain of controllers forwarding to the next action, when their respective content couldn't be found?

I also want to avoid having a single action that checks every type of content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can intercept the request and do your magic with your own router listener.

I didn't test it myself but I just wanted to point you into the right direction.

In your service.xml file you can add something like that:

```
    <parameters>
        <parameter key="my.router_listener.class">MyBundle\Listener\RouterListener</parameter>
    </parameters>

    <services>
        <service id="my.router_listener" class="%my.router_listener.class%">
            <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.entity_manager" />
            <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber" priority="33" />
        </service>
    </services>
```

The priority here is important. 32 is the default router. You want to be just befor it. http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/dic_tags.html

Then create the service like this:

```
class DynamicRouterListener extends RouterListener
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        //...
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $path = $request->getPathinfo();

        // Some magic here
        if(// magic is true) {
            $request->attributes->set('_controller', 'MyBundle:MyController:myAction');
        }
    }
}
```

The default router, that comes next, will see that the _`controller` parameter is already there and will skip the matching to the dafult rules.

Comment: Thanks, this is a much better approach than using a controller action to decide where to forward the request, and doesn't require any extra handling for a 404. I guess building on this, the best way of having global routes without risking collisions or requiring a series of database queries, would be to have a `Route` entity related to each type of content? They could be fetched on mass (and cached in production) for a service used by my router event listener, that would handle checking if the requested URI exists?

Comment: @Adam I think it is a design question. Sure, you can create as many listeners as type of objects you want to have but the question is how many types will you have and how likely it is to change in the future? If, as you mentioned in your post, you have 3 types then I would suggest to handle it in one class. Just keep it small.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can, not fully or without risking collisions.

You'll need something that will tell the router which thing you're referring to, or it can't know in any way if it's a product, a page or a brand. At the very least, you'll need to manually avoid name collisions.

You can set up 3 routes, with that matching pattern, like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{page-slug}")
 *
 *
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function pageAction(PageClass $page)
{
     ...
}
```

but you can't decide which tries to match first inside the Router; so, in case of a collision, you're basically screwed.

Comment: This is exactly what the author does not want to do.

Comment: Mmmh, I put some more thought in it, and you're right. I'll edit the answer

Comment: Thanks, but as mentioned, using a controller action to forward on to other actions is what I'm trying to avoid.